# C# log4net: DateTimeFormat with blanks

Tags: c#, log4net, datetime-format

I am using the RollingFileAppender(log4net) to log events of 24/7-application in a file.
The file name have to be as follows:

"blabla-2012- 3- 6.txt" or "blabla-2012-13- 6" or "blabla-2012- 3-12.txt"

The problem is that I dont know a DateTime format, that would use blanks instead of zero.

```
RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender ();
                 appender.Name = String.Format ("{0} appender_", name);
                 appender.File = string.Format ("{0} {1} {2} {3}", logPath, @ "\", file, name, extension);
                 appender.AppendToFile = true;
                 appender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
                 appender.StaticLogFileName = false;
              ->> Appender.DatePattern = string.Format ("yyyy-M-d");
....
```

Comment: Can't you use /10 to determine weather the month/day is single character and append " " then the month/day?

Comment: today im using NLog with a custom event-context. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventContext-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4net uses the following to determine the file name in the rolling file appender:

```
m_scheduledFilename = 
CombinePath(File, m_now.ToString(m_datePattern, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
```

where as you guess m_now is the current datetime. So you can use all DateTime [available custom formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), and I think the format you need is not present out of the box. 
So if you absolutely need such a format you can write a custom appender by deriving it from `RollingFileAppender` and overriding the `RollOverTime` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can place literals in the format string:

```
Appender.DatePattern = "yyyy- M- d"; // don't need string.Format
```

Does that not work?

Edit: I understand now: You want MM, but instead of "05" you want " 5". DateTime formatting does not have a way to facilitate this. You could create your own derivative RollingFileAppender that tries to handle this special case formatting.

Comment: And when it's 13 Oct it'll be 2012- 10- 13 as far as I can work out